# Correct syntax for if statement in saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

Running following command:
`salt host1 file.check_perms /xxx/zzz '{}' root sudo 0750`
I will get True,
I like add this to my state, but can't find the correct syntax.

```
{% if not salt['file.check_perms']('/xxx/zzz/', '{}',['root'],['sudo'],['0750']) %
Set group ownership and permissions:
  file.directory:
    - name: /xxx/zzz/
    - user: root
    - group: sudo
    - dir_mode: 750
    - file_mode: 750
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
      - mode
{% endif %}
```

Traceback:

```
 Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:certbot.cert' failed: Jinja error: string indices must be integers, not unicode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 392, in render_jinja_tmpl
    output = template.render(**decoded_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 13, in top-level template code
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/file.py", line 4469, in check_perms
    orig_comment = ret['comment']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, following syntax is works:

```
{% if salt['file.check_perms']('/xxx/zzz/', {},('root'),('sudo'),('0750')) != 'True' %} 
Set group ownership and permissions:
  file.directory:
    - name: /zzz/zzz/
    - user: root
    - group: sudo
    - dir_mode: 750
    - file_mode: 750
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
      - mode
{% endif %}
```